# Has there been any research done in fluid dynamics within a mobius strip?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I was wondering if there has been any research done with the flow of fluid within a mobius strip?

The reason I am interested is, assuming the fluid would flow around a center axis point, at certain points the strip with be perpendicular to the circular plane around the axis while the opposite side will point directly at it. I would imagine this would cause a Coriolis force but it would apply to all fluid identically (assuming it is all flowing at the same speed at the perpendicular part) however it cannot all react the same?

would/could the fluid flow all at the same speed at the part of the mobius strip that points toward the axis?

Comment: A Möbius strip is two dimensional; do you mean a related three dimensional analog?

Comment: Yes that should definitely make the scenario work better.

Comment: So maybe like a [Klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle)?

Comment: actually like this http://i.imgur.com/Gfe5O.png

Comment: I think he just means a slightly extruded & hollowed Mobius strip

Comment: An object traveling on the surface of that object would see it as a Mobius strip, but a fluid flowing through the interior would see it as a misshapen torus. The flow would be complicated I'm sure, but the fact that the surface is constructed from Mobius strips doesn't cause any particularly "special" flow effects.